# Location/Country based user redirection using ip2locale module

Tags: redirection, multi-sites

I am using IP to Locale (7.x-1.x-dev) for redirect the user to a multilingual website based on user country.
I used the following modules also.

IP to Locale - WebHosting.info
IP to Locale - Redirect

In Configuration » Regional and language » IP to Locale » Country Code to Language Code mappings i have:

gb,en

us,en

ch,de
But its not working? Its not redirecting.Any one help me?

Comment: You can try [IP Language Negotiation](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_language_negotiation) module.